# Configurando jsTree para AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

Estou usando o plugin [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/), tentando fazê-lo buscar as informações por [AJAX](http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/).

No *server side* tenho quatro tabelas no banco, sendo cada uma um nível da árvore.

```
Tabela1
-Tabela2
--Tabela3
---Tabela4
```

Fazer o plugin buscar o primeiro nível foi fácil:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    core: {
        data: {
            url: "/tabela1.json"
        }
    }
});
```

Mas não estou conseguindo acertar a sintaxe para fazê-lo buscar os outros nível, ao clique do usuário.

As duas tentativas abaixo não funcionaram:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    core: {
        data: {
            url: "/tabela1.json",
            data: "/tabela2.json"
        }
    }
});

$("#tree").jstree({
    core: {
        data: {
            url: "/tabela1",
            data: {
                url: "/tabela2.json"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Como estão organizados esses JSON? Telvez você precise de uma função se quiser controlar os subníveis. O jsTree é relativamente simples de usar, mas não estou conseguindo entender o que você está tentando fazer. Tem como mostrar as estruturas do JSON e como você quer organizá-las?

Comment: @Bacco É a primeira vez que utilizo este plugin. Eu ocultei os nomes das tabelas porque não convêm ao problema. Mas Tabela1 possui muitas Tabelas2, que possui muitas Tabelas3, que possui muitas Tabelas4. Para economizar banda, a ideia é buscar confirme o clique do usuário.

Comment: @Bacco No *server side* tenho rotas que retornam o formato correto que o jsTree pede, ou seja, `{'id': 1, 'text': 'Texto'}` e aceitam filtro por *query string*.

Comment: Acho que é o caso de você criar a sua função de load então, que é o parâmetro do data dos nodes http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/ no final da página.

Comment: @Bacco Neste caso tenho que usar `$.getJSON` e passar o retorno para a função `cb`?

Comment: @user7261 Estou estudando pra fazer um, quando terminar posto meu codigo pra vc.

Comment: @user7261 segue minha lógica postada aqui no Stack.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43477/montar-%C3%A1rvore-jstree/44949#44949

Answer (score 1):

Pq vc não faz a chamada das tabelas cada uma por vez?

```
var urls = [];
urls[0] = "/tabela1.json";
urls[1] = "/tabela2.json";
urls[2] = "/tabela3.json";
urls[3] = "/tabela4.json";

for(i=0; i < urls.length){
    $("#tree").jstree({
        core: {
            data: {
                url: urls[i];
            }
        }
    });
}
```