# Como popular um TreeView com uma lista do banco?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Eu tenho um `TreeView` estático que representa pastas e arquivos nesse modelo:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
<Nodes> 
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Diretorio1"  Target="_blank">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo1 "  Target="_blank"/>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo2"  Target="_blank"/>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo 3"  Target="_blank"/>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="diretorio2" NavigateUrl="~/Employer.aspx" Target="_blank">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo1" Target="_blank"/>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo2"  Target="_blank"/>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo3"  Target="_blank"/>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Diretorio3" Target="_blank">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo1"  Target="_blank"/>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo2"  Target="_blank"/>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="arquivo3"  Target="_blank"/>
    </asp:TreeNode>
</Nodes>
```

E tenho dois métodos no Entity Framework: Um que retorna uma lista de diretórios e outro que retorna lista de arquivos de um determinado diretório. Ambos já funcionam e quero aplicar no meu modelo.

Como ficaria para me popular esse `TreeView` com esses meus métodos?

Comment: Você já ouviu falar em JSTREE?

Comment: sim, porem preciso com o treeView nesse modelo que ta ai.

Comment: Pouco tempo atrás usei esse aqui. Muito melhor que o treeviw
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43477/montar-%C3%A1rvore-jstree

Comment: mas ja uso treeview, e ja personalizei, mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, é so fazer um foreach em cada lista sua, e criar os Node via c#.

Primeiramente, comente com o <%  --%>  o codigo dos nodes no seu webforms, ou remova deixando apenas a declaração do TreeView, pois o mesmo será dinamico agora, deixe apenas isso:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
```

Depois no seu pageLoad:

```
 var listDiretorios = metodoListarDiretorio();
 var listArquivos = metodoListarArquivos();
        foreach (var diretorio in listDiretorios)
        {      
            TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(diretorio.nomeDiretorio);
            node1.NavigateUrl = "#"; //link 
            node1.PopulateOnDemand = false;
            node1.ImageUrl = "~/asstes/img/directory.png";
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node1);

            foreach (var arquivo in listArquivos)
            {
                TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode(arquivo.nomeArquivo);
                node2.PopulateOnDemand = true;
                node2.NavigateUrl = "#";
                node2.ImageUrl = "~/asstes/img/file.png";
                 //adiciona o node2 ao node1
                node.ChildNodes.Add(node2);
            }

        }
```

Basicamente foi so criar uma lista para o primeiro node (diretorios), depois criar uma no mesmo momento para o segundo node (arquivos) , e adicionar um node no outro. 
OBS: Já deixei setado seu icone de pastas e arquivos.

Comment: Deu certo, perfeitamente aqui valeu.