# Percorrer json multidimencional javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse json `[{"id":1,"id_pai":null,"id_usuario":1,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},[{"id":2,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":2,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},{"id":3,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":3,"ordem":2,"lado":"2"}],[{"id":4,"id_pai":2,"id_usuario":4,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"}],[{"id":2,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":2,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},{"id":3,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":3,"ordem":2,"lado":"2"}]]`

Preciso percorrer e transformar isso, nisso, os dados que faltam, eu vou adicionar depois.

```
{ id: 0, parent: null, description: "Nivel do Peão", email: "emailDo@Cabra.com", groupTitleColor: "#4169e1", image: "demo/images/photos/q.png", itemTitleColor: "#4169e1", phone: "(19) 98111-9983", title: "Nome do Peão", label: "Nome do Peão" }
```

Como faço para percorre-lo com javascript?

Pergunta 2, como eu faço para não passar pelos itens duplicados?

Comment: Não é mais fácil modificar sua query que monta esses dados? Sua pergunta é sobre Jstree?https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43477/montar-%C3%A1rvore-jstree

Comment: Sim, em tese, o problema é que eu estou consumindo esse js de uma api que me devolve na forma inicial, a segunda forma, é a qual eu preciso deixar para rolar na estrutura de dados para rodar no plugin que estou usando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lembre-se que isto são json's dentro de arrays: `[{"id":1,"id_pai":null,"id_usuario":1,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},[{"id":2,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":2,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},{"id":3,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":3,"ordem":2,"lado":"2"}],[{"id":4,"id_pai":2,"id_usuario":4,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"}],[{"id":2,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":2,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},{"id":3,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":3,"ordem":2,"lado":"2"}]]`

Aqui está o que você pode fazer!

Quando é array você pode subscrever e pegar o resultado final! Veja:

```js
   var text = [{"id":1,"id_pai":null,"id_usuario":1,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},[{"id":2,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":2,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},{"id":3,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":3,"ordem":2,"lado":"2"}],[{"id":4,"id_pai":2,"id_usuario":4,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"}],[{"id":2,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":2,"ordem":1,"lado":"1"},{"id":3,"id_pai":1,"id_usuario":3,"ordem":2,"lado":"2"}]];

   text[0].cidade = "Cuiabá"; // Criando novo valor
   text[0].id = 99999; // Subscrevendo o valor antigo

   text = text; /* Subscreve o array de json antigos para o atual com mudanças */

   console.log(text); // Imprime no console do navegador
```

Com JSON's:

```js
var text = {
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
};

// Mudando valores
text.employees[0].firstName = "Maicon";
text.employees[0].lastName = "Ferreira";
// Adicionando valores
text.employees[0].cidade = "Cuiabá";
text.employees[0].estado = "Mato Grosso";
text.employees[0].pais = "Brasil";

// Prescrevendo valores
text = text;
// Imprimindo no console
console.log(text);
```

Se ajudei não esqueça de classificar como resposta correta!